# как вычесть от даты и времени дату и время? Laravel, Carbon

Tags: laravel, carbon

```
к примеру есть
date_start1 = 2022-06-08 22:41:00
date_start2 = 2020-02-08 00:50:00

Нужно узнать сколько времени осталось до date_start1 и date_start2

в данном примере date_start2 уже просрочен

//вот так что-то не хочет
$diff = Carbon::parse('2020-06-09 08:20:00')
      ->diff(Carbon::now())
      ->format('Y-m-d H:i') //return string 'Y-m-d H:i'
```

нужно чтобы вернуло осталось столько то часов или 0 если просрочен

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $dateStart1 = Carbon::parse('2022-06-08 22:41:00');
    $dateStart2 = Carbon::parse('2022-06-08 22:41:00');
    $diff1 =$dateStart1->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());
    $diff2 =$dateStart2->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());
```

Вы можете юзануть вместо `diffInMinutes`: `diffInSeconds`, `diffInDays`, `diffInHours`, `diffInWeeks`, `diffInWeeks`, `diffInYears` или в флоатном формате каждый из перечисленных, как этот `floatDiffInMinutes`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateStart1 = Carbon::parse('2022-06-08 22:41:00');
$dateStart2 = Carbon::parse('2024-02-08 00:50:00');

$now = Carbon::now(); // 2023-07-11

$diff1 = ($dateStart1 < $now) ? $dateStart1->diffInHours($now) : 0; // 9549
$diff2 = ($dateStart2 < $now) ? $dateStart2->diffInHours($now) : 0; // 0
```